# mahapps.metro using icons styles with datatrigger

Tags: styles, icons, datatrigger, mahapps.metro

I want to data trigger on an Icon but i can not find out how to do this :( I tried this code baut is does not work can any one help pleaaaase ?

```
<Style x:Key="ConnectionIcon" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ConnectionStatus}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Resources">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_disconnect}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ConnectionStatus}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Resources">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_connect}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Use Snoop to check if the bindings are working or broken... When you say it does not work can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick for this by using the `OpacityMask` and simple change the `Fill` property of the `Rectangle`.

```
<Style x:Key="ConnectionIcon"
        TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ConnectionStatus}"
                  Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Fill"
              Value="Green" />
      <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
        <Setter.Value>
          <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                        Visual="{StaticResource appbar_disconnect}" />
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ConnectionStatus}"
                  Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Fill"
              Value="Red" />
      <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
        <Setter.Value>
          <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                        Visual="{StaticResource appbar_connect}" />
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, this dosen´t work. The fill setter without OpacityMask works as expected but with OpacityMask the icon stays blank